# Open File Dialog and Opening different File

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on Opening a file(s). Requirement is, if user select Text in the filter, user can select mulitiple files. But if user selects any image files, user is allowed to select single file.

One way of doing is, capturing dialog.FileOk deleagate and intial checks.

Do we have any other ways of achiving the same.

Thank you,

Comment: please be more specific and clear and post some code if y have written

Answer (score 0):

[OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1kh29w3.aspx) does not provide events for FileSelected, or FilterChanged. So, with default [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1kh29w3.aspx) you can only subscribe to FileOk event and cancel or accept it after user made selections. If you want to change settings on the fly (e.g disabling multiple files selection when user choose images in filter) then you should extend [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1kh29w3.aspx). Unfortunately default one is sealed, thus you can't just inherit from that. So, take a look on these articles:

- [Customizing OpenFileDialog in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16276/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET)
- [Extend OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog the easy way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

   if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      System.IO.StreamReader sr = new 
         System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
      MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
      sr.Close();
   }
```